# pandas won't rename multiindex column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename, multi-index

I've just spent several hours trying to get this to work and I'm starting to think I want the impossible, though I'm pretty sure it can be done. I have a pandas dataframe which has a multiindex header (excel spreadsheet, 3 rows header). I am definitely looking at it, so I know it exists, yet when I try to rename a column according to the official documentation, I'm told the column name can't be found.

The table looks like this:

```
Test              | Test1         | Test2
                  | abc   | xyz   | abc   | xyz
geo1    | geo2    | geo1  | geo2  | geo1  | geo2
------------------------------------------------
a       | x       | 1     | 0.5   | 1     | 0.5
b       | y       | 2     | 0.2   | 2     | 0.2
c       | z       | 3     | 0.4   | 3     | 0.3
```

I simply want to change "Test" into "Boom", for example. Test is the first value of the column names in level 0, yet it doesn't work. I used one of these:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0][0]: 'Boom'}, inplace=True, errors='raise')
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0][0]: 'Boom'}, level=0, inplace=True, errors='raise')
df.rename(columns={df.columns.values[0][0]: 'Boom'}, inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

Problem is, even if I hard code the column names and level, it still doesn't work! This should do the trick as it works in other scripts of mine (2 levels, not 3):

```
df.rename(columns={'Test': 'Boom'}, level=0, inplace=True, errors='raise')
```

The error is funny, as it's telling me it can't find the "Test" column (it's literally telling me it can't find the column it just names...). What am I doing wrong??

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you able to print df.columns[0][0] ? Does it give you 'Test'?

Comment: yes, printing df.columns[0][0] returns the column name I want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.columns.set_levels(['Boom1','Boom2','Boom3'],level=0,inplace=True)
```

If your columns are Boom1, ..., Boom1000, first create a list of names by

```
ll = [f"Boom{i}" for i in range(1,1001)]
df.columns.set_levels(ll,level=0,inplace=True)
```

Comment: how do I achieve this without having to manually type in the column names? I got 20+ columns, not 3 as in the example (though they are the same format).

Comment: they're all completely different names, hence my need to rename one of them only. any way I can replicate the existing list of column names, but replace one of them in the process? thanks

Comment: @Chris change the comprehension to `['Boom' if x == 'Test' else x for...]`

Answer (score 0):

I just removed errors='raise' from the function and it worked. there's no logic in the way pandas works, but this seems to have done the trick. not sure how something can work, but if you tell it to raise an error if needed, it stops working. thanks all for trying anyway. if someone could explain why this is the way it is, for my own sanity, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: "there's no logic in the way pandas works" that's unnecessary

Comment: not exaggerating or anything, but where's the logic in something raising an error that stops the script if not specifying that an error should be raised achieves the desired result? since it does work, it means that label IS in the index, yet if a parameter is set, pandas decides it's not there.

Comment: The method's docstring explains it pretty clearly. I think your issue is coming from using 'inplace'. See my answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

This combination of parameters works for me:

```
index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 'X'), ('B', 'Y'), ('C', 'Z')], names=['id1', 'id2'])
columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Test1', 'a', 'x')], names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    data = [1, 2, 3],
    index=index,
    columns=columns
)

df.rename(columns={'Test1': 'Boom!'}, level='col1')
```

which return a new dataframe:

```
col1    Boom!
col2        a
col3        x
id1 id2      
A   X       1
B   Y       2
C   Z       3
```